# Weblogic 11g Changing network while server is running breaks Datasource connections

Tags: weblogic, datasource, weblogic11g, network-connection

On my Laptop's installation of Weblogic 11g, Changing network (WIFI to Wired etc.) while the server is running seems to break Datasource connections.
I have to reboot (which takes forever) to get my apps running on Weblogic to work again. 
I tried to go over the Data Source connection settings in the Console to disable "this" monitoring. But couldn't find a way to turn it off.

Wondering if there's a way to turn this freaky behavior off.

Comment: So you disconnect your computer from the network (briefly) when you switch from wired to wifi... of course your connection is going to break. If you have more than one server the communication between them will break as well. Am I missing something here? Best case you edit your JDBC settings in the admin server and make sure `Connection Retry Frequency` is set

Answer (score 2):

Try the following two steps in your connection pool settings:

1. Select "Remove Infected Connections Enabled"
2. Reduce "Test Frequency"